# JSON is parsed incorrectly in Powershell script and I do not know why

Tags: json, powershell

I have the following JSON (from an REST API):

```
{
    "QueryBD_REST_CI_01Response": {
        "rsStart": 0,
        "rsCount": 3,
        "rsTotal": 18872,
        "BD_REST_CI_01Set": {
            "CI": [
                {
                    "CINAME": "ciname_number_one",
                    "CINUM": "cinum_number_one",
                    "CISPEC": [
                        {
                            "ALNVALUE": "value_one",
                            "ASSETATTRID": "SCOPEOFADMINISTRATION"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "CINAME": "ciname_number_two",
                    "CINUM": "cinum_number_two",
                    "CISPEC": [
                        {
                            "ALNVALUE": "value_two",
                            "ASSETATTRID": "SCOPEOFADMINISTRATION"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "CINAME": "ciname_number_three",
                    "CINUM": "cinum_number_two",
                    "CISPEC": [
                        {
                            "ALNVALUE": "value_three",
                            "ASSETATTRID": "SCOPEOFADMINISTRATION"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have saved this particular piece of json in a file (dummydata.json). In Powershell I run the following command:

```
$dummydata = Get-Content -Raw -Path G:\CMDB_FNMSDB_vergelijking\dummydata.json | ConvertFrom-Json
echo $dummydata
```

And the results that I see are the following:

[image]

BD_REST_CI_01Set is empty here where I expect to see data (CI array and its contents). I checked the JSON on https://jsonlint.com/ and it validated succesfully. Maybe I just don't know how to fetch that piece of data but I believe its not here in Powershell.

Why do I not see the data?

Comment: I don't think it's actually empty, this is simply a mirage of formatting :) Try `(G:\CMDB_FNMSDB_vergelijking\CMDB_FNMSDB.ps1).QueryBD_REST_CI_01Response.BD_REST_CI_01Set`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You were right, the data is there, if you know how to find it :). Thanks!

Comment: A good trick to see the whole tree: `... |Format-Custom` or turn it back into JSON: `... |ConvertTo-Json` :)

Answer (score 0):

I typically write a script which reads the JSON from the file and then parses it. Ths script is something like this:

```
foreach ($name in $x) {
    if ( $name.name_with_namespace -match ".*myProjectName.*" ) {    
        write-host "$($name.name_with_namespace) - $($name.id)"               
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
-Suhas